# Json results abc.json file instead of view

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am practicing MVC asp.net for first time, and I am trying to get List of products from Controller to View through Jquery $.ajax or $.getJSON method, below is the function in controller:

```
 public ActionResult List()
    {
      Dictionary<string, List<Product>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<Product>> {{"pList", PList}};
      return Json(dict,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and ajax function is:

```
 $(window).load(function () {
 $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("List", "Product")',
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#div").append("<table><tr><td>ID</td><td>Name</td><td>Description</td><td>Price</td></tr>");
            data.pList.each(function () {
                $("#div").append("<tr>");
                $(this).each(function () {
                    $("#div").append("<td>" + $(this).Id() + "</td>");
                    $("#div").append("<td>" + $(this).Name() + "</td>");
                    $("#div").append("<td>" + $(this).Description() + "</td>");
                    $("#div").append("<td>" + $(this).Price() + "</td>");
                });
                $("#div").append("</tr>");
            });
            $("#div").append("</table>");
        }
    });
});
```

on loading \Product\List it renders List.json file on browser rather than redirecting to \Product\List and creating dynamic table as provided in success function of ajax. I followed many tutorials that shows this method is correct.

Comment: Call your view's method.

Comment: Return your view first, and then use an object to trigger AJAX call (e.g. `ActionLink` or button) instead of directly using `$(window).load`.

Comment: Thank you , it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

load(function () {
 $.ajax({
        url: '/List/product',
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#div").append("IDNameDescriptionPrice");
            data.pList.each(function () {
                $("#div").append("");
                $(this).each(function () {
                    $("#div").append("" + $(this).Id() + "");
                    $("#div").append("" + $(this).Name() + "");
                    $("#div").append("" + $(this).Description() + "");
                    $("#div").append("" + $(this).Price() + "");
                });
                $("#div").append("");
            });
            $("#div").append("");
        }
    });
});`